To identify the following SMD component marked "157 F118 05L"
I need help in identifying this SMD component.
Which has the following marking code
"157
F118
05L"
Which has 9 pin or 6 pin QFN package.


It's a Bosch BMM150 geomagnetic sensor.


(Source: lcsc.com)
